# R: Shiny, plotly, renderTable and POSIXct

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I'm using shiny to return a list of points clicked in a `ggplotly` plot displaying a time series. When I render a table, it doesn't show the timestamps as datetimes but as a number. Apparently, `renderTable` uses `xtable`, and [xtable doesn't play nicely with dates and POSIX objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652674/r-xtable-and-dates).

I found numerous answers suggesting to just convert timestamps into `as.character` or `strftime`, e.g. this one: [Showing POSIXt object with Shiny renderTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15500451/showing-posixt-object-with-shiny-rendertable) . But for one, this doesn't seem to work either for me, it also crashes my R when I try to actually do it for my entire (large) dataset.

There gotta be a way to only format the individually clicked points inside the server routine instead of the entire Timestamp column outside? Apparently `renderDataTable({})` instead of `renderTable({})` [is supposed to help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21548843/r-shiny-different-output-between-rendertable-and-renderdatatable), but that's not even drawing any table for me at all.

```
df<-data.frame(Timestamp=as.POSIXct(c('2018-03-28 09:52:27',
                           '2018-03-28 09:57:32',
                           '2018-03-28 10:05:55',
                           '2018-03-28 10:12:32')),
               V1=c(5, 3, 10, 7))

p<-ggplot(df, aes(x=Timestamp, y=V1))+
  geom_line(linewidth=0.5) +
  geom_point()

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("plot"),
  tableOutput("dataTable")
)

d_save <- data.frame()

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    ggplotly(p) 
  })
  
  output$dataTable <- renderTable({
    d <- event_data("plotly_click")
    d_save <<- rbind(d_save,d[2:4])
    data.frame(d_save)
  })  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: Shiny and ggplotly]

```
#df$Timestamp2<-strftime(df$Timestamp, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
df$Timestamp3<-as.character(df$Timestamp)

p<-ggplot(df, aes(x=Timestamp3, y=V1))+
  geom_line(linewidth=0.5) +
  geom_point()

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: Shiny and plotly 2]

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to convert the `x` of the event data to a date time using `as.POSIXct` before binding the data to `d_save`. And then use `renderDataTable` to render your table, which of course requires to use `dataTableOutput` in the UI (Perhaps this was the issue why you did not get a table?).

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("plot"),
  dataTableOutput("dataTable")
)

d_save <- data.frame()

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    ggplotly(p)
  })

  output$dataTable <- renderDataTable({
    d <- req(event_data("plotly_click"))
    
    d$x <- as.POSIXct(d$x)
    d_save <<- rbind(d_save, d[2:4])  
    
    d_save
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Even when I copy&paste your code, I get a "'origin' must be supplied" error. For some reason, ```event_data()``` is not even returning the timestamp as a timestamp but it appears it's already converted into a number during that step, despite showing a datetime upon click/hover in the plotly plot

Comment: Adding to my previous comment, if I work with as.Date objects instead of POSIXct, it works. I still do not understand why it appears to be working even with POSIX for you, but not on my end.

Comment: I just checked again. And the code works fine on my Mac. Perhaps an issue related to the R version? I'm using R 4.3.2 and just saw in the docs that the `origin` argument is only optional since R 4.3.0. But to provide the origin you might try `origin = as.POSIXct("1970-01-01", tz = "GMT")`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried Stefan's suggestion and it still wasn't working for me. It worked if I changed my POSIXct timestamps to dates with `as.Date()`, but that isn't desirable. I then tried a different approach plotting my data with `plot_ly` instead of `ggplotly` and that appears to do the trick. I do not know why, but there seems to be something going on with ggplottly on my end.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("plot"),
  tableOutput("dataTable")
)

d_save <- data.frame()

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(x= ~df$Timestamp, y = ~df$V1, type='scatter')
    
  })
   
  output$dataTable <- renderTable({
    d <- req(event_data("plotly_click"))    
    d$x <-as.character(d$x)
    d_save <<- rbind(d_save, d[2:4])      
    d_save
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: Example using plot_ly]