# R shiny table with dates

Tags: r, date, shiny

I'm making an app to analyse some data with Shiny.

When I directly send query to database, I can see good rezults:

[image]

But when I try to put results from this query to shiny, column 'not_outlier_date' look different:

[image]

I want to have the same date format, as in the first picture.

I was trying, on table, that I get from database, add:

```
  not_outlier_dates[,2]<-as.Date(as.numeric(as.vector(unlist(not_outlier_dates[,2]))))
```

But it doesn't make any changes and works with warning:

```
 Warning in formatC(x = c(16065, 16137, 16064, 15707, 16063, 15775, 15782 :
 class of 'x' was discarded
```

How can I solve this date format problem?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try using this:

```
not_outlier_dates[,2] <- as.character(not_outlier_dates[,2])
```

The problem lies in the `xtable` library that `Shiny` uses to display tables. It seems there are bugs related to `date columns`, as stated in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652674/r-xtable-and-dates) and this (closed) [Shiny issue](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/129). Not sure if that still applies or if it applies to your `xtable` version, though.

Comment: The problem still exists as of November, 16th 2022